# Jaspic ServerAuthModule delegating to JAAS Krb5LoginModule

Tags: java, jboss, kerberos, spnego, jaspic

I have to write a custom Jaspic ServerAuthModule (which needs to add a proprietary Authentication Cookie to the HTTP Response AND HTTP Request to be propagated to the applications running on the App Server). The Authentication must be done using Kerberos, SPNEGO.

The Application Server to be used is JBOSS EAP 6.4.x

I managed to get the Authentication using the JAAS Krb5LoginModule working.

The JBOSS EAP *Standone.xml* I use:

```
  <security-domain name="host" cache-type="default">
    <authentication>
      <login-module code="com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule" flag="required">
          <module-option name="debug" value="true"/>
          <module-option name="principal" value="HTTP/macbookAirRCH@EXAMPLE.COM"/>
          <module-option name="storeKey" value="true"/>
          <module-option name="useKeyTab" value="true"/>
          <module-option name="doNotPrompt" value="true"/>
          <module-option name="keyTab" value="/Users/jet/Downloads/kerberos/macbookAirRCH.keytab"/>
      </login-module>
    </authentication>
  </security-domain>
  <security-domain name="SPNEGO" cache-type="default">
    <authentication>
      <login-module code="SPNEGO" flag="required">
          <module-option name="serverSecurityDomain" value="host"/>
      </login-module>
    </authentication>
    <mapping>
      <mapping-module code="SimpleRoles" type="role">
          <module-option name="user@EXAMPLE.COM" value="User,Admin"/>
      </mapping-module>
    </mapping>
  </security-domain>
```

*jboss-web.xml*:

```
 <jboss-web>
   <security-domain>SPNEGO</security-domain>
   <valve>
       <class-name>org.jboss.security.negotiation.NegotiationAuthenticator</class-name>
   </valve>
   <context-root>kerberosREST</context-root>
 </jboss-web>
```

I also managed to get a customized JASPI Module working (`extends org.jboss.as.web.security.jaspi.modules.WebServerAuthModule`) using the following configuration:

```
<security-domain name="testDomain" cache-type="default">
   <authentication-jaspi>
      <login-module-stack name="lm-stack">
         <login-module code="SPNEGO" flag="required">
            <module-option name="serverSecurityDomain" value="host"/>
         </login-module>
      </login-module-stack>
      <auth-module code="ch.test.jaspic.CustomServerAuthModule" flag="required" login-module-stack-ref="lm-stack"/>
    </authentication-jaspi>
       <mapping>
          <mapping-module code="SimpleRoles" type="role">
             <module-option name="user@EXAMPLE.COM" value="User,Admin"/>
             </mapping-module>
          </mapping>
 </security-domain>
```

*jboss-web.xml*:

```
<jboss-web>
   <security-domain>testDomain</security-domain>
   <valve>
       <class-name>org.jboss.as.web.security.jaspi.WebJASPIAuthenticator</class-name>
   </valve>
   <context-root>kerberosREST</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

How can I use the default JAAS Krb5LoginModule?

Should I include the two valves in the jboss-web.xml? (the order is important)

*jboss-web.xml*:

```
<jboss-web>
   <security-domain>testDomain</security-domain>
   <valve>
       <class-name>org.jboss.security.negotiation.NegotiationAuthenticator</class-name>
   </valve>
   <valve>
       <class-name>org.jboss.as.web.security.jaspi.WebJASPIAuthenticator</class-name>
   </valve>
   <context-root>kerberosREST</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

> The Application Server to be used is JBOSS EAP 6.4.x

Unfortunately JASPIC isn't implemented very well on this version of JBoss. JBoss EAP 7 will be fine and should be released (if all goes well) this year or perhaps early next year (but nobody knows, not even the people at JBoss). There are several betas of EAP 7 out, the latest one is called JBoss WildFly 10 and a slightly earlier is called EAP 7 beta 1.

In general, there's a JAAS bridge where you let your JASPIC SAM call your JAAS Login Module. You need to understand that a JASPIC SAM is the authentication mechanism and the JAAS Login Module is the identity store.

I'm pretty sure you *do not* need the JBoss specific configuration of the JAAS Login Module. That is only needed to let JBoss internal code (e.g. their implementation of the Servlet FORM authentication mechanism) find that module.

If JASPIC is used, the SAM is in control.

For the bridge profile, see this article for more info:

https://blogs.oracle.com/nasradu8/entry/loginmodule_bridge_profile_jaspic_in

Comment: thank you for taking the time to reply. Unfortunately, the version of JBOSS EAP I must use is fixed to 6.4.x. If I understand it correctly, thelogin bridge profile is exactly what is used under the hood of my JASPIC SAM (which extends org.jboss.as.web.security.jaspi.modules.WebServerAuthModule). This also works just fine, if the LoginModule I delegate the identity store does not require SPNEGO (HTTP Basics for example). Do you have any ideas how to configure the JASPIC SAM and the JBOSS valves to enable SPNEGO with the JASPIC SAM? Thank you

Comment: My bad, not sure the WebServerAuthModule actualy delegates to the LoginModule. I will have a look at the 'DelegatingServerAuthModule'.

Answer (score 3):

To my (little) understanding, `Valve`s are, roughly speaking, a lower-level, container-specific and container-wide Servlet `Filter` counterpart. Therefore what you are trying to do should indeed work with the pipeline (`Valve` sequence) presented in your question. When `NegotiationAuthenticator` has completed the actual authentication, `WebJASPIAuthenticator`--the `ServerAuthModule` (SAM) ultimately delegated to by it--would check whether an authenticated *caller* `Krb5Principal` (or whatever `Principal` JBoss wraps it with) has been associated with the request by the former, and set the cookies accordingly.

I wonder why you are even willing to use JASPIC merely for setting cookies though, when you could just use a simple `Filter` instead (and get rid of some of that JBoss-specific configuration as a bonus). Or you could alternatively, if you were willing to give up any trace of authentication mechanism portability, try to extend `NegotiationAuthenticator`, overriding its `authenticate(...)` method and setting the cookies from there, depending on the outcome of a delegation to the overriden implementation.

And finally there's the proper (albeit harder) vendor-neutral approach, where you would drop `NegotiationAuthenticator` and re-implement its functionality as a SAM. Who knows--an open-source SPNEGO SAM might even exist somewhere out there. For Kerberos authentication you could reuse the existing `Krb5LoginModule`<sup>1</sup>, by delegating to it--as dexter meyers [wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36218967/3986374)--in accordance with JASPIC's *LoginModule Bridge Profile* (chapter 6 of the specification). `LoginModule`s (LMs) are of course not supposed to be used directly, but via `LoginContext`s, which in turn need some `Configuration` to find the right LM through and initialize it with. Whether you are going to reuse JBoss's `Configuration` (and therefore retain the respective proprietary XML), provide your own persistent representation, or just hard-code it in a custom `LoginContext` / `Configuration` is your choice.

<sub><sup>1</sup> Ideally you would re-implement the LM too, perhaps in a second SAM, orchestrating calls to the two from a separate `ServerAuthContext`. Doing so would reduce the proprietary authentication-related configuration to zero, at the cost of added complexity and code to maintain.</sub>

Comment: Thank you for your time. I will indeed have a look at the org.jboss.security.auth.container.modules.DelegatingServerAuthModule. I did not want to use a Filter, because I think, that the logic which needs to be run an every request (Cookies checks for authentication, if not authenticated, Krb5 redirect...) too complex for a Filter is. Moreover, as far as I know, one can add Cookie to an HttpServletResponse, but not to an HttpServletRequest. I do know, that this case is a bit special, but I really need to be able to add the Cookie the Response and Request.

Comment: I will try to configure the Valves as suggested in my question, using DelegatingServerAuthModule and comment back. Regarding re-implementing the NegotiationAuthenticator's login in my custom JASPIC SAM: I thought about it, but wanted to try (as far as possible) to prevent me from doing it... I will also look for an Open Source SPNEGO SAM. If somebody  has a pointer, I would be thankful.

Comment: (1/3)
*> "I did not want to use a Filter..."*
Okay, so unless I get this wrong, you have to set cookies *during* the authentication message exchange. Then neither the `Filter` nor the simple SAM option are of any use, since, whenever the preceding `NegotiationAuthenticator` issues redirects, your component being second in the chain won't get invoked at all. You will either have to hook into the authenticator itself somehow, or ditch it in favour of a SAM-based (re-)implementation. If I find such a SAM, I'll let you know.

Comment: (2/3)
*> ...one can (not) add cookies to an HttpServletRequest*
You would have to wrap the request within an `HttpServletRequestWrapper` (overriding its `getCookies()` to return the additional `Cookie`) and pass the wrapper down the `FilterChain`.
*> "I will try to configure the Valves [...] using DelegatingServerAuthModule..."*
Calling the LM a *second* time (`NegotiationAuthenticator` already invokes it, indirectly) doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: (3/3)
Boilerplate is awful, but non-portable code is bad too. Therefore, rather than extending JBoss-specific SAMs, consider authoring your own convenience abstractions--an HTTP-tailored SAM and maybe bare bones implementations of the factories--*once* and move on from there, instead. If portability trully is of no concern to you, I see little benefit in using JASPIC anyway, instead of vendor-specific authenticators and LMs. But that's usually not the case, as otherwise the majority would write components against, say, Weld's and OpenEJB's APIs too, rather than their Java EE counterparts.

Comment: [This](https://java.net/projects/spnego/sources/svn/content/trunk/core/src/main/java/net/java/spnego/SpnegoServerAuthModule.java) SAM, as well as [this](http://blogs.nologin.es/rickyepoderi/index.php?archives/74-SPNEGOKerberos-in-JavaEE-spnego.java.net.html) article examining it may be of interest.